# Find all the factors of a given number

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, algorithm, factors

The most basic code(i guess so) to find all the factors of a number

Note:factors include 1 and the number itself

Here's the code:

```
c=0
x=int(input("Enter number:"))
for i in range(1,x+1):
    if x%i==0:
        print("factor",c+1,":",i)
        c=c+1
print("Total number of factors:",c)
```

Please make this code efficient.....ie: Help to reduce the number of iterations

Comment: What range of numbers are you interested in? The best approach for `x` on the order of \$10^{8}\$ is not the same as the best approach for `x` on the order of \$10^{80}\$.

Comment: i may need like 10^40s to 10^60s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to have a more readable (than the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220618/98493) by [@Justin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/195671/justin)) and complete (than the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220617/98493) by [@Sedsarq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/201168/sedsarq)) version of the algorithm presented in the other answers, here is a version that keeps the factors in a `set` and uses the fact that factors always come in pairs:

```
from math import sqrt

def get_factors(n):
    """Returns a sorted list of all unique factors of `n`."""
    factors = set()
    for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.update([i, n // i])
    return sorted(factors)
```

Compared to your code this has the added advantage that it is encapsulated in a function, so you can call it repeatedly and give it a clear name and docstring describing what the function does.

It also follows Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which programmers are encouraged to follow.

With regards to which code is fastest, I'll let this graph speak for itself:

[image]

For the `op` function I used this code which has your checking of all factors up to `x`:

```
def op(x):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        if x%i==0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors
```

And the `factors` function is from the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220618/98493) by [@Justin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/195671/justin).

---

If all you really want is the number of factors, the best way is probably to use the prime factor decomposition. For this you can use a list of primes together with the algorithm in the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220727/98493) by [@Josay](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9452/josay):

```
from math import sqrt
from functools import reduce
from operators import mul

def prime_sieve(limit):
    prime = [True] * limit
    prime[0] = prime[1] = False

    for i, is_prime in enumerate(prime):
        if is_prime:
            yield i
            for n in range(i * i, limit, i):
                prime[n] = False

def prime_factors(n):
    primes = prime_sieve(int(sqrt(n) + 1))
    for p in primes:
        c = 0
        while n % p == 0:
            n //= p
            c += 1
        if c > 0:
            yield p, c
    if n > 1:
        yield n, 1

def prod(x):
    return reduce(mul, x)

def number_of_factors(n)
    return prod(c + 1 for _, c in prime_factors(n))
```

Comparing this with just taking the `len` of the output of the `get_factors` function and this function which implements your algorithm as `op_count`:

```
def len_get_factors(n):
    return len(get_factors(n))

def op_count(n):
    c = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            c = c + 1
    return c
```

The following timings result (note the increased range compared to the previous plot):

[image]

Comment: But doesn't it depend on the workability of the solutions too? The code you provided for the op function doesn't give the right answer for factors of `30` - `[30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]` and Sedsarq's answer only gives two factors - `(5, 6)`, meanwhile both of our answer's give the right solution - `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30]`.

Comment: @Justin Well, it does emulate the behavior in the OP, which just prints the factor instead of saving it in a list. So what you are actually saying is the code provided in the question is not working (which would make it off-topic)? I did not include any code from sedsarq's answer because it is not complete enough, as you say.

Comment: @Justin Nevermind, my `op` function gave the wrong answer for all numbers, because I saved `x` and not `i`... This should not change the runtime, though.

Comment: The code I shared was not intended as a full solution, but simply to clarify the text. My answer just aimed to present an idea to use for improvement (and that idea is also used by the other solutions given here).  @Justin

Comment: Thanks buddy...I want to make it more concise though...I'm greedy....suppose consider 100......50 is one of its factor....but 50 already contains 2 and 5 so we can say 10 is also a factor...this logic will reduce the runtime much more...but how to implement this?..any ideas?

Comment: @THEEPICGUY For this you would need to start at the number itself and go down (otherwise you would already have found both 2 and 5 before getting to 50). It would also mean you have to check every number as well as factorize every number, since you might otherwise miss a prime factor. Factorizing is a lot harder than finding out if the number divides `n`, as you should know since that is the problem you are solving. This would also probably be a recursive solution, which are usually not the best solutions in Python.

Comment: @THEEPICGUY  Where you can gain is if you only care about the prime factors. Then you just take a list of all prime factors below `sqrt(n) + 1` and try them all. This is a lot more efficient than trying every number below the sqrt bound, obviously, by at least a factor two (there is only one even prime, 2).

Comment: @Graipher The problem of "sqrt(n) + 1" is that suppose consider the number 666(lol just for fun)....the "sqrt(666) + 1" is 26.8 so if we find all the factors of 26.8...We are missing the number '37' which is also a factor of 666 (37*18) so this method is wrong and pointless...any better methods?

Comment: @THEEPICGUY See the answer by Josay, which basically implements this. They also stop at sqrt(x). They could use a list of primes instead of trying every `d`.

Comment: @Graipher Yet it doesn't give all the factors of the given number!! Even he is wrong...the sqrt(n)+1 is can only be used to check whether a number is prime or not....it can't be used to give all the factors of the given number :( ...But decompostion to primes seems like a nice idea...yet i can't find a way to implement...i'm trying though

Comment: @THEEPICGUY It is possible to get the number of factors from the prime factor decomposition (see comment under their answer).

Comment: @THEEPICGUY See updated answer. I verified that the algorithm does get the prime factors of 666 correct.

Comment: @Graipher....yes your updated prime decomposition is epic...but can u use an explicit for loop instead of the reduce function (cause the function is currently deprecated) and it slows the algorithm.... Yeah....but this is actually the solution I needed....thanks though

Comment: @THEEPICGUY While the Python 2 built-in `reduce` was deprecated and removed in Python 3, using `functools.reduce` is fine, if needed. IMO the `prod` function is the one and only place where it is still widely used and it is justified there. If your really need to, just change it to a `for` loop in your code.

Comment: Can u add one more feature....checks josay's replies....I specified I needed that extra feature...that may make my code even faster....

Comment: @THEEPICGUY I don't understand what you mean. I already only use the primes needed. If you have a pre-existing list of primes (guarenteed to be large enough), just use `itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n < limit, primes)` to restrict it to the ones you need.

Answer (score 4):

All answers provided are great and offer suggestions with a complexity in `O(sqrt(n))` instead of the original `O(n)` by using the trick to stop at `sqrt(n)`.

On big inputs, we can go for an even faster solution by using the decomposition in prime numbers:

- the decomposition in prime numbers can be computed in a time proportional to the square root of the biggest prime divisor if its multiplicity is one (the actually complexity is actually a bit more tricky than this)
- the decomposition can be reused to generate all possible divisors (for each prime `p` with multiplicity `n`, you take `p ^ m` with `0 <= m <= n`.

I can provide the following piece of code for the first task but I do not have a snippet for the second task (yet?)

```
def prime_factors(n):
    """Yields prime factors of a positive number."""
    assert n > 0
    d = 2
    while d * d <= n:
        while n % d == 0:
            n //= d
            yield d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:  # to avoid 1 as a factor
        assert d <= n
yield n
```

Edit: I tried to implement the second step and got something which is not highly tested but seems to work:

````
def mult(iterable, start=1):
    """Returns the product of an iterable - like the sum builtin."""
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, iterable, start)


def yield_divisors(n):
    """Yields distinct divisors of n."""
    elements = [[p**power for power in range(c + 1)] for p, c in collections.Counter(prime_factors(n)).items()]
    return [mult(it) for it in itertools.product(*elements)]
```
````

Comment: This sounds interesting...but suppose if a number can be broken into p^x *q^y...where p and q are primes then number of factors are just permutation of x and y....but how do we permute them? Any ideas?

Comment: I guess the itertools module can be very useful here. Maybe itertools.product...

Comment: @Josay You don't even need the permutations, you just need to count how often each prime occurs: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relationship-between-prime-factors-and-total-number-of-factors-of-a-number

Comment: @Graipher To get the number of factors, this is indeed much easier. You can use nb_divisors from my code in https://github.com/SylvainDe/ProjectEulerPython/blob/master/prime.py . Getting the different divisors is slightly more complicated

Comment: @Graipher I've also implemented the generation of the different divisors, you can have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Wow...this is much faster...great algorithm.... Yet can you make a small change (I tried and I couldn't do it)...like....already there are some 100 first primes stored in the list which I'll use rather than generating each time...but if the prime factors exceed the list then I'll use the function to give some more primes and append in the list.... Can u try this?

Comment: @THEEPICGUY I think would make a much more complicated implementation... I am not sure I want to go that way.

Answer (score 3):

Divisors come in pairs. Since 2*50 = 100, both 2 and 50 are divisors to 100. You don't need to search for both of these, because once you've found that 100 is divisible by 2, you can do 100 / 2 to find 50, which is the other divisor. So for every divisor you find, use division to find its "partner" at the same time. That way you don't need to look further than the square root of x:

```
for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1):
    if x % i == 0:
        divisor1 = i
        divisor2 = x // i
```

Comment: If you are really very concerned about speed, since you only need the sqrt to define a limit, you could use a faster, more approximate sqrt method. As long as it convergences from above the true sqrt, you won't go below the limit (and maybe miss a divisor).

Comment: The sqrt method is only called once though. There's not a lot of time to save there. @HoboProber

Comment: So we need sqrt(n)+1?...won't this contain all the divisors....of course this one reduced my time by half....so far so good...is it possible to reduce further?...like suppose 100...the factor 50 has 2,5 already in it right....so with that we can say 10 is a factor...is it possible to implement such logic in our code?

Answer (score 2):

Since you say in a comment that you may need to find the divisors of a number \$n\$ up to \$10^{60}\$, trial division is not practical, even if performed only up to \$\sqrt n\$ . The only option is to find the prime factorisation and then reconstruct the divisors from the prime factorisation.

There are quite a few [algorithms to find the prime factorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms). For the size of numbers that interest you, the [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) is probably the best option.

Given the prime factorisation, reconstruction of the divisors is just a matter of taking some Cartesian products. Generating them in order is slightly trickier: I reproduce here some code which I wrote for an earlier answer to a similar question. It assumes that `primeFactors` gives output in the form `[(prime, power) ...]` in ascending order of primes.

```
import heapq

def divisors(n):
    primes = [(1, 1)] + list(primeFactors(n))
    q = [(1, 0, 1)]
    while len(q) > 0:
        # d is the divisor
        # i is the index of its largest "prime" in primes
        # a is the exponent of that "prime"
        (d, i, a) = heapq.heappop(q)
        yield d
        if a < primes[i][1]:
            heapq.heappush(q, (d * primes[i][0], i, a + 1))
        if i + 1 < len(primes):
            heapq.heappush(q, (d * primes[i + 1][0], i + 1, 1))
            # The condition i > 0 is to avoid duplicates arising because
            # d == d // primes[0][0]
            if i > 0 and a == 1:
                heapq.heappush(q, (d // primes[i][0] * primes[i + 1][0], i + 1, 1))
```

Comment: Yeah...this is what I wanted...but can u simplify without using heapq...(idk what it does...and I don't want to use unnecessary functions).... I kinda found the code till I get the prime factors and their respective powers and stored them in separate lists...now I just need the code for Cartesian product...ie:permuting the powers of the primes....can u help me?

Comment: This site is code *review*, not a code writing service. Supplying improved code is already going above and beyond expectations.

Comment: lol...agreed...anyways...thanks for informing...i just joined stack overflow recently..my bad